# How to check attributes belongs to specific product in opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am trying to get products those have multiples specific attribute.
I mean to say ,i want search those product that have "type"=rings and "metal"=gold

i tried with **IN** operator but is the alternative of OR operation.I need AND operation.

product_attribute table there is only product_id,attribute_id,so how do i perform and operation in mysql

opencart version 1.5.4

I've tried the query below

```
SELECT *   FROM oc_product_attribute  WHERE product_id=42 AND attribute_id=15 AND attribute_id=17
```

output is blank

Comment: Please update your question with the current mysql query, output of that query and the output needed.

Comment: Change `attribute_1d` to `attribute_id` !!

Comment: Are you trying to come up with a query for the filters in categories so they have 'AND' logic between groups, if so you will not achieve it with IN() except if you are gonna change the base structure.

Comment: IN nothing but OR operation but i want AND operation because i want to display those product that have attribute_id 15 and 16."base structure" table structure

Comment: I can not understand what you are saying... Opencart by default has OR logic implemented in their filters in categories.  First of all explain if you want this logic you are saying in the filters or in another part? Secondly explain what you actually want the reaction to be by differentiating attribute groups and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have **OR** logic between attributes in the same group and **AND** logic between attributes in different groups you should:

1. go to **"catalog\model\catalog"** edit product.php
2. The function you need to edit is `public function getProducts($data = array(), $get_all = FALSE) {`
3. At the start of the function specify these variables: `$validimi = false; $filter_groups = array();`
4. Find this code:

   ```
   if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                       $implode = array();

                       $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

                       foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
                           $implode[] = (int)$filter_id;
                       }

                       $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
   ```

   }
5. and add this piece just before `$sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";`

   ```
               $sql_check = "SELECT DISTINCT (filter_group_id) FROM  " . DB_PREFIX . "filter WHERE filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ") ";    
               $query_check = $this->db->query($sql_check);
               $filter_groups = array();
               foreach ($query_check->rows as $result) {
                   $filter_groups[$result['filter_group_id']] = array();
               }

               if(count($filter_groups) > 1){
                   $validimi = true;               
               }else{
                   $validimi = false;
               }
   ```
6. finally find this piece of code in the function i specified:

   $sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";
7. and change it to:

   ```
     If( $validimi ) {
   ```

   $sql .= "GROUP BY p.product_id HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT pf.filter_id)=".count($filter_groups);

   ```
       }else{

           $sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

       }
   ```

now try your filters they should work fine, this is what i created and used on my own stores but with opencart version 1.5.5.1 but i think it will work fine in your case too. The logic is clear so in case that this code does not help you, you can use the logic to create your own :).

Hope i helped.